# How to display text from left to right

Tags: css

I have to display a question as follow:

[image]

But i couldn't align the answer labels because they haven't the same size, here's what i get:

[image]

So How to make the texts write from left to right as shown in the first screenshot?

Comment: Hey. There are multiple ways of doing this... what browser do you support? Perhaps the simplest way of doing this would be with tables, but flexbox is a great solution too. Can you please provide some code, what have you got so far?

Comment: please show us what you tried so far

Comment: Try to make 3 columns of html tables. in first column, set align left and rest will be as default on right.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add the bellow CSS to your label tags

```
 label{
    display:inline-block; 
    width:120px;
    text-align:right;
 }
```

or use a table with border="0" attribute and align="right" for firsts columns

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a table (columns are auto-sized by default), to easily create this layout:

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td:first-of-type {
  text-align: right;
}

table td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* Borders added only to see the cells */
  border: 0 solid #ccc;
  border-width: 2px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Fonds structuré :</td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="fond" /><span>Oui</span></label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="fond" />Non</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Obligation :</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="oblig" />
      <label>Oui</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="oblig" />
      <label>Non</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Assurance-vie ou action :</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="assu" />
      <label>Oui</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="assu" />
      <label>Non</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content{
padding: 20px;
}

.text_col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input_col {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text_col p {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="text_col">
    <p>
      Next of Kin:
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="input_col">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" />
    <label for="s1">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input_col">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" />
    <label for="s2">No</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
  <div class="text_col">
    <p>
      Gender:
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="input_col">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" />
    <label for="s1">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input_col">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" />
    <label for="s2">No</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
  <div class="text_col">
    <p>
      Relationship with Next of Kin:
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="input_col">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" />
    <label for="s1">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input_col">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" />
    <label for="s2">No</label>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```